# How to build Firefox extention to intercept HTTP requests and responses?

Tags: http, firefox, request, intercept

how do I insert a listener to Firefox http requests and responses, so that I popup a window with the address requested and the response body?

**Note:** 
I have to do this building an extension to Firefox. 
I need a button to activate or disable the feature. 
For every request, I need to popup a window with an "Ok" button to allow the request to be made. Likewise, I need to popup a window with the response body from the web server, with an "Ok" button to allow the content to be displayed by the browser.

I know that I have to use *nsIHttpChannel*, as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_HTTP_request_headers), but ***I don't know where to put such code on the extention's architecture***. 
I have very little knowledge about javascript. 
 
Could anyone help me?

Comment: The best way to figure out these things is to find a extension that already does this and look at the source.  All FF extensions are open source!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, BlueRaja. But not all FF extensions are open source (http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/155919).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help to take a look at Firebug source code

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/

Comment: Thanks Midhat. I'll check it out.